# Continue Session from UI to API in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Problem Statement: In my application there is a token which is unable to generate it from the api call directly and other way because the it is implemented with OAUTH. So I took a detour and automate it through API. by using Webdriver sampler. with following script.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('appurl');
java.lang.Thread.sleep(10000);
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("details-button")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("proceed-link")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("i0116")).sendKeys("username"); //enter user name and password in login.microsoft.com
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("idSIButton9")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("i0118")).sendKeys("password");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("idSIButton9")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("idSIButton9")).click();
//WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

This works fine and I am able to retrieve the token by using regex extractor.
[image]

[image]

Using the Token in API Call and getting retry error

**JMeter Failure (getting IO error exceeded number of retry =, tried with 20, 50 ,200 and now 500)**

[image]

**Browser:**
[image]

Suspecting the session id may be I am not transferring or is there anything I am missing (remember I am not terminating the browser session)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I would be in your shoes, I should go with Dmitri answer. But we had a similar issue recently and we were sending `JSessionId` and `Dead-SessionId` in the cookie. We resolved by doing following

1. Add a `Http Cookie manager` to your test plan.
2. In the UI sampler please add the sample code,

   `WDS.vars.putObject('sessionCookies', WDS.browser.manage().getCookies())`
3. Add a `JSR223 PreProcessor` to your `Http request` with following script

   ```
   vars.getObject('sessionCookies').each { scookie ->
   sampler.getCookieManager().add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie
   (scookie.getName(), 
   scookie.getValue(), 
   scookie.getDomain(), 
   scookie.getPath(), 
   scookie.secure, 
   System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000))
   ```

   }

In our case we were not sending the expiry which was giving us

```
ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getTime() on null object at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
```

So we replaced `cookie.getExpiry().getTime()` with `System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to copy the [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) from the browser to the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Add the next line to your WebDriver Sampler code:

   ```
   WDS.vars.putObject('cookies', WDS.browser.manage().getCookies())
   ```
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler where you want to copy the session from the UI and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.getObject('cookies').each { cookie ->
       sampler.getCookieManager().add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue(), cookie.getDomain(), cookie.getPath(), cookie.secure, cookie.getExpiry().getTime()))
   }
   ```
4. That's it, the HTTP Request sampler should send the cookies now and you should be authenticated

More information on manipulating cookies with Groovy code: [Modifying Cookies in JMeter with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/modifying-cookies-in-jmeter-with-groovy)

Comment: Thank you mate, but getting 2022-05-23 14:26:19,166 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getTime() on null object
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]

Comment: It seems that some cookie doesn't have expiration date, you can replace `cookie.getExpiry().getTime()` with `cookie.getExpiry().getTime() ?: System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400000L` to set artificial expiration date to be 1 day ahead just in case. More information: [Groovy Elvis Operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator) and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: my apologies Dmitri for not accepting your answer but below answer resolved my issue.

Comment: It's a copy-paste of my answer